# How to create a list of overlapping segments of a string in R?

Tags: r, string, split, segment

For a string like ‘ABCDEFG’, is it possible to split into different lists of overlapping segments with different lengths?
For example, with 2 letters: ‘AB’, ‘BC’, ‘CD’,’DE’,’EF’,’FG’.
With 3 letters: ‘ABC’, ‘BCD’, ‘CDE’, ‘DEF’, ‘EFG’
And so on.
These segments should be a shift for just one letter rather than simple split.

Thank you very much.

Comment: consecutive ≠ overlapping ;-)

Comment: Oh sorry. Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not that good and I don't know if that's what you searched, but I think it might do the trick with package stringr.

```
string <- "ABCDEF"
library(stringr)

combinated_letters <- function(string, n) {
  length_ <- str_length(string)
  str_sub(string, seq(1, length_ + 1 - n), seq(n, length_))
}

combinated_letters(string, 1)
combinated_letters(string, 2)
combinated_letters(string, 3)
combinated_letters(string, 4)
combinated_letters(string, 5)
combinated_letters(string, 6)
```

With the result :

```
> combinated_letters(string, 1)
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F"
> combinated_letters(string, 2)
[1] "AB" "BC" "CD" "DE" "EF"
> combinated_letters(string, 3)
[1] "ABC" "BCD" "CDE" "DEF"
> combinated_letters(string, 4)
[1] "ABCD" "BCDE" "CDEF"
> combinated_letters(string, 5)
[1] "ABCDE" "BCDEF"
> combinated_letters(string, 6)
[1] "ABCDEF"
```

Answer (score 2):

There’s no builtin way, unfortunately. That said, doing this manually is fairly straightforward.

Given:

```
x = 'ABCDEFG'
len = 3L
```

```
start = seq_len(nchar(x) - len + 1L)
result = vapply(start, \(s) substr(x, s, s + len - 1L), character(1L))
```

Or, wrapped in a function (as mentioned, these overlapping substrings are called “ngrams”):

```
ngrams = function (x, len) {
  start = seq_len(nchar(x) - len + 1L)
  vapply(start, \(s) substr(x, s, s + len - 1L), character(1L))
}
```

Alternatively you can use `substring()` instead of `substr()` + `vapply()`, because `substring()` is vectorised:

```
ngrams = function (x, len) {
  start = seq_len(nchar(x) - len + 1L)
  substring(x, start, start + len - 1L)
}
```

However, since it uses cyclic expansion of its argument lengths, `substring()` is somewhat error-prone when the input isn’t what was expected.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, these are called **n-grams**, in this case, character n-grams. *n* is equal to the number of characters you want to extract.

You can use existing functions to extract those very efficiently:

#### With **[`stringdist`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/index.html)**:

```r
stringdist::qgrams("ABCDEFG", q = 2)

#    AB BC CD DE EF FG
# V1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

This will return a table of counts for each character bigram/n-gram (use a different value for `q`).

#### With [`quanteda`](https://quanteda.io/):

```r
library(quanteda)

"ABCDEFG" %>% 
  tokens("character") %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  char_ngrams(2, concatenator = "")

# [1] "AB" "BC" "CD" "DE" "EF" "FG"
```

This will return the list of bigrams/n-grams (change the value of `n`).
You can optionally activate the options `remove_punct` (to remove all punctuation) or `remove_symbols` in `quanteda::tokens()` if you need some preprocessing.

Comment: Those 2 options are way slower than the one from @Guillaume Mulier

Comment: An even faster option is found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77148479/8806649

Comment: The ` stringdist` prpposed solution is not correct