# Split a string in consecutive substrings of size n in R in an efficient way

Tags: r, string, n-gram

```r
# Input
n <- 2
"abcd" 
# Output
c("ab", "bc", "cd")
```

I don't want to use  a `for` loop or `sapply`

Comment: See: [How to create a list of overlapping segments of a string in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68903565)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use `substring` -

```
get_n_grams <- function(string, n) {
  len <- nchar(string)
  substring(string, seq_len(len - n + 1), n:len)    
}

get_n_grams("abcd", 2)
#[1] "ab" "bc" "cd"

get_n_grams("abcd", 3)
#[1] "abc" "bcd"
```

Comment: Is it possible to vectorise the function with respect to `string`?

Comment: Using the current answer, I don't think so. Your best bet would be `sapply(string, get_n_grams, 2)`

Answer (score 1):

This `embed` trick could work but might be not as efficient as the [`substring` approach by @Ronak Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77148479/12158757)

```
> n <- 2

> s <- "abcd"

> apply(embed(utf8ToInt(s), n)[, n:1], 1, intToUtf8)
[1] "ab" "bc" "cd"
```

Comment: `embed` has a `for` loop inside

Comment: OMG you are doing a thedailyWTF  here -- converting what might or might not be utf8 there and back again!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft just for fun, not for serious