# generate sequence of consecutive and overlapping numeric blocks

Tags: r, sequence

From this

```
x <- 1:10
block.size <- 3L
```

I would like to generate a sequence of consecutive and overlapping blocks of length 3 like so:

```
1,2,3
2,3,4
3,4,5
4,5,6
5,6,7
6,7,8
7,8,9
8,9,10
```

I found [this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68903698/1979665) which works with characters.

I can think of a loop to do this, but I would definitely prefer a more concise and vectorized way if possible. Here is my take.

```
block.nums <- length(x)-len+1
blocks <- vector(mode = "list", length = block.nums)

for (i in 1:block.nums) {
  blocks[[i]] <- i:(i+block.size-1)
}
```

Comment: is it important to you that the numbers are in increasing order? I see in your example they are, but in your description you don't mention this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [`embed()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/embed)

```
> embed(x, block.size)[, block.size:1]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    3    4
[3,]    3    4    5
[4,]    4    5    6
[5,]    5    6    7
[6,]    6    7    8
[7,]    7    8    9
[8,]    8    9   10
```

---

Or, `sequence`

```
matrix(
    sequence(
        rep(1 + length(x) - block.size, block.size),
        from = head(seq_along(x), block.size)
    ),
    ncol = block.size
)
```

which gives the desired output as well

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    3    4
[3,]    3    4    5
[4,]    4    5    6
[5,]    5    6    7
[6,]    6    7    8
[7,]    7    8    9
[8,]    8    9   10
```

Comment: I just tested this with `x <- 1:10000
block.size <- 100`, and the sequence version you wrote is about 115 times faster than the slowest answer. Bravo!

Comment: @Mark aha, that's an interesting observation, I didn't know that before :P

Comment: So many great answers! I decided to accept this one (the embed one)  since it seems to me the most concise and straight way to do it (personal preference). Thanks to you (and all other users that provided their answers, +1 to everybody :)

Answer (score 4):

You could try:

```
ll <- length(x) - (block.size - 1) # number of rows
mat <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(x) - (block.size - 1), ncol = block.size) # initiate a blank matrix

sapply(seq_len(block.size), \(xx) mat[,xx] <- x[seq_len(ll) - 1 + xx])
```

Output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    3    4
[3,]    3    4    5
[4,]    4    5    6
[5,]    5    6    7
[6,]    6    7    8
[7,]    7    8    9
[8,]    8    9   10
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way (most likely slower than the others):

```
vapply(head(x, -block.size), \(s) seq(s, s + block.size - 1), integer(block.size)) |> t()

# Output is the same as the other ones ;)
```

Notes:

1. `vapply()` is similar to the other `*apply()` functions, but requires you to add an output type and size. The documentation says it is sometimes faster (though doesn't specify in which situations, frustratingly!)
2. `head()` in this case is getting everything except the last `block.size` elements of x

Answer (score 3):

Here a function

```
> f <- \(n, s) {
+   stopifnot(s > 0 && s <= n)
+   if (s == 1) as.matrix(seq_len(n))
+   else t(sapply(1:(n - s + 1L), `+`, 0:(s - 1L)))
+ }
> f(10, 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    3    4
[3,]    3    4    5
[4,]    4    5    6
[5,]    5    6    7
[6,]    6    7    8
[7,]    7    8    9
[8,]    8    9   10
> f(5, 2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    2    3
[3,]    3    4
[4,]    4    5
> f(5, 1)
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3
[4,]    4
[5,]    5
> f(1, 1)
     [,1]
[1,]    1
> f(5, 6)
Error in f(5, 6) : s > 0 && s <= n is not TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

A possibility would be to use `outer`.

```
outer(1:8, 0:2, `+`)
#outer(seq_len(length(x)-block.size+1), 0:(block.size-1), `+`) # Alternative with given data
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    3
#[2,]    2    3    4
#[3,]    3    4    5
#[4,]    4    5    6
#[5,]    5    6    7
#[6,]    6    7    8
#[7,]    7    8    9
#[8,]    8    9   10
```

Or `matrix` with auto repeat and vector addition.

```
matrix(0:2, 8, 3, TRUE) + 1:8
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    3
#[2,]    2    3    4
#[3,]    3    4    5
#[4,]    4    5    6
#[5,]    5    6    7
#[6,]    6    7    8
#[7,]    7    8    9
#[8,]    8    9   10
```